# How to run an exe from a AutoHotKey script?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a .exe  which I have converted from .bat. I want to run that .exe file from AHK. How do I write a script for this case?

Is it something like this - run, converted.exe, hide or run, path.converted.exe, hide?

Comment: Did you try what you have suggested? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

Just use this :

```
Run, filename.exe
```

Comment: To illustrate, you can also add the whole path as in `Run, "C:\Program Files\HWiNFO64\HWiNFO64.EXE"`